# How to store a spark DataFrame as CSV into Azure Blob Storage

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to store a Spark DataFrame as a CSV on Azure Blob Storage from a local Spark cluster

First, I set the config with the Azure Account/Account Key (I'm not sure what is the proper config so I've set all those)

```scala
sparkContext.getConf.set(s"fs.azure.account.key.${account}.blob.core.windows.net", accountKey)

sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.azure.account.key.${account}.dfs.core.windows.net", accountKey)
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.azure.account.key.${account}.blob.core.windows.net", accountKey)
```

Then I try to store the CSV with the following

```scala
filePath = s"wasbs://${container}@${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${prefix}/${filename}"
dataFrame.coalesce(1)
  .write.format("csv")
  .options(Map(
    "header" -> (if (hasHeader) "true" else "false"),
    "sep" -> delimiter,
    "quote" -> quote
  ))
  .save(filePath)
```

But then this fails with `Job aborted` and the following stack trace

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
```

But when I look in the blob container, I can see my file however I cannot read it back in a Spark DataFrame, I get this error `Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.;` and following stack trace

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:185)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:185)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:184)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
```

It seems that the problem was already reported on [Databricks forum](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/15675/writing-dataframe-to-a-blob-storage.html)!!

What is the proper way to store a DataFrame on Azure Blob?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out way before the job fails there was an internal error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob(Ljava/net/URI;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/AccessCondition;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/AccessCondition;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobRequestOptions;Lcom/microsoft/azure/storage/OperationContext;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsOutputStream.restoreKey(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:918)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsOutputStream.close(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:876)
    ... 18 more
```

What's happening is after creating a temp file with the actual data, it's trying to move the file to the location given by the user using `CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob`. Like always, microsft people broke this by renaming this method to `CloudBlob.startCopy`.

I'm using `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-azure" % "3.2.1"` which is most recent for `"hadoop-azure"` and it seems to have stuck with the older `startCopyFromBlob`, so 
I need to use an old `azure-storage` version that has this method, probably 2.x.x.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/113