# No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs error in Hadoop 3.2.1

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, azure-blob-storage

I've a spark cluster (v 2.4.0) running on k8s (for now it's AKS). I'm trying to read files in Spark dataframe with following schema

```scala
s"wasbs://${container}@${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${prefix}"
```

In my scala code I did set the hadoop configs as follows

```scala
    sparkContext.getConf.set(s"fs.azure.account.key.${account}.blob.core.windows.net", accountKey) sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.azure.account.key.${account}.dfs.core.windows.net", accountKey)sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.azure.account.key.${account}.blob.core.windows.net", accountKey)
```

I am able to read the file when I use in my project `build.sbt`

`"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-azure" % "2.7.3"`

but when I try using version `3.2.1` which is the latest I get the following error `No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs` with this stasktrace

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
```

Comment: Is the Hadoop cluster actually using Hadoop 3.2.1?

Comment: Are you following this guide https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/index.html?

Comment: I've added more details, we are running spark on k8s so the hadoop config I had to added them in scala.

Comment: FYI my original problem was this one (unfortunately the only way it worked for me is by downgrading azure libraries versions to back 2015!!) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482695/how-to-store-a-spark-dataframe-as-csv-into-azure-blob-storage